# Getting all Article links from an infinite scolling webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, rss, beautifulsoup

I program with python and am using beautiful soup to parse in articles from [The History Channel's News Feed](http://www.history.com/news/did-florida-host-the-first-thanksgiving). As of now, I can figure out how to get the article text from the individual articles, but I can't figure out how to get the links from the infinite feed. I tried plugging into the RSS feed and using feedparser, but that only gives the 20 most current articles.

Is there a way to get more that I am missing? Pythonic methods preferred!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, infinite scrolling is usually handled by injecting records from paginated results that could be accessed directly from a url.

Using [Postman Interceptor](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/capture), you can discover the url schema for the paginated results.

The second page of results for this page is: http://www.history.com/api/html/news?sidebars=aetn_content&includejs=aetn_content&page=2

Loop over the pages and scrape away!